# How to increment count using session and id of a file using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, count

Below shows my coding to increment the number of publication view for my website. Right now it increments whenever I click refresh. I have used session command on some part of the code however it doesn't work, it increments whenever I click refresh. I want to understand how can I not make user to increment the session if they are in same session.

It will be very grateful if you can help me.

```
<?php   
session_start();
$_SESSION['counted'] = true;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $file_id = ($_GET['id']); //$id is a new vairable given value to the id selected in publication.php

    if ($file_id <= 0) { //check if id is less than or equal to 0
        die('The ID is invalid, please check the technical process!');
    } else {
        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id='$file_id'");

        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = 0;
            $query = "UPDATE files SET visitors=visitors+1 WHERE id='$file_id'";
            mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close();
            session_destroy();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is incrementing each time you refresh is because of the following line of code:

```
session_destroy();
```

What it's doing is (as the name depicts) destroying your session after each increment, so next time the page loads, $_SESSION['id'] is no longer instantiated, so your **if(!isset($_SESSION['id']))** always returns true.

You can try the following:

```
<?php   
session_start();
$_SESSION['counted'] = true;

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $file_id = ($_GET['id']); //$id is a new variable given value to the id selected in publication.php

    if ($file_id <= 0) { //check if id is less than or equal to 0
        die('The ID is invalid, please check the technical process!');
    } else {
        mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE id='$file_id'");

        if (!isset($_SESSION['id'][strval($_GET['id'])])) {
            $_SESSION['id'][strval($_GET['id'])] = true;
            $query = "UPDATE files SET visitors=visitors+1 WHERE id='$file_id'";
            mysql_query($query);
            mysql_close();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I've used an array $_SESSION['id'] to store a key for each different page ID, then each time we test if we need to increment your counter, we check if an array key exists for that page, if it does, we don't increment.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: The problem with taking out session destroy, is that when i leave the page and go to another page with the same counter but different id, it does not increment. However, like you said if we do destroy the session it will forever increment the counter of that page id. So for instance: php?id=149 & php?id=150 are different pages but use the same counter.

Comment: I am sorry say that it is still giving me error saying "Cannot use a scalar value as an array in" on line where you put "$_SESSION['id'][$_GET['id']] = true;". Do you have any clue on this type of error?

Comment: Ah, I apologise. You'll need to convert it to a string first. That way it will be an associative array. I'll fix my answer when I get access to a computer again.

Comment: Sure. I will wait for you.

Comment: I am having still problem with it. It says "Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in" in the line "  if (!isset(strval($_SESSION['id'][$_GET['id']]))) {".

Comment: I apologise, I accidentally put strval() in the wrong spot.  I've been able to test my latest edit and it should work. :)

Comment: You are awesome seriously. Thank you very much for the support, really appreciated. Take care. You are great.

Comment: Thanks mate. Please mark the question as "answered" if it solved your problem. :)  It was my pleasure!